# I can't create the jquery selector I need

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I couldn't manage to count some `<li>`s with the jquery selector. Actually I can only do one part of it. I need to count `li`s that has class `working` and doesn't have class `error`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$("#upload > ul > li.working")
```

which gives me the `li`s that has class `working` but I couldn't figure out how could I ignore  `li`s that has bot `working` and `error` class. I tried below with no luck:

```
$("#upload > ul > li.working, li:not(error)")
```

Comment: The expression `#upload > ul > li.working, li:not(error)` will pick `#upload > ul > li.working` **or** `li:not(error)`; also `li:not(error)` will yield nothing because an element can't be `<li>` and `<error>` at the same time.

Comment: I knew that wasn't going to be the solution :) Thanks to answers I managed to get it work ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use:

```
$("#upload > ul > li.working:not(.error)")
```

Comment: I just tried this and it works as expected. I knew it was a little thing to do, but when you couldn't do it you couldn't do it :) I will accept this as answer in 10 mins ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `not()` to avoid the elements

Try with

```
$("#upload > ul > li.working").not('.error')
```

or, alternatively, the `:not()` method:

```
$("#upload > ul > li.working:not(.error)")
```